# How to turn an integer value into a double decimal value?

Tags: java

I want to parse two integer values into a double value, where the end product should look like this:

```
int value;
int decimalValue;
double result;

result = value . decimalValue;
```

How can I do this most elegantly for integer values of variable lengths?

Edit: What I could do is something like this:

```
String temp = String.valueof(decimalValue);
int i = temp.length();
double d = decimalValue;

for (i > 0; i--) {
    d / 10;
}

d = d + value;
```

However, I wouldn't call that very elegant. Is there a better solution for my problem?

Edit: Was made aware of a flaw in my thinking. As such, I am using now Strings instead of integer values and BigDecimal instead of a double value.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What if decimal value should be 003, but an int will only hold the value of 3? This may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about that, Guess I will turn those integer values into strings instead.

Comment: I want to turn two user inputs into a double value, representing an amount of money. I went with two user inputs because the 'cents' field holds a default value, to be more convenient for the user.

Comment: You may find that `double` isn't the best data type for storing amounts of money.  Would you consider using `BigDecimal` instead?  Or just keep your money as two `int` values, maybe.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the value after the decimal is cents, then just divide it by 100, add to the dollar value, and you'll have your correct answer.  Of course, you will need to verify that the cents are in the range [0 .. 99] inclusive to prevent overflow problems, but that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks for the heads up, I'll use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Double.parseDouble(value + "." + decimalValue);
```

But like Hovercraft Full Of Eels said in the comments storing something like 003 in an integer will not work.